# Chrome: Obtain HTTP/2 Log from net-internals

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, http2

Is there a way to programatically obtain the HTTP/2 logs from

`chrome://net-internals/#http2`

either through selenium or a commandline option?

I want to do automated tests with HTTP/2 and i am using selenium-chromedriver.

I know that you can access the perflogs from chromedriver, however those seem to hide many HTTP/2-specific things such as priority, or stream id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to start chrome with `--log-net-log=output.json`.

However, currently there is a bug in chromedriver that truncates the log.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1688#c1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fiddler Core C# API

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
                Monitor.Enter(oAllSessions);
                oAllSessions.Add(oS);
                Monitor.Exit(oAllSessions);
        };
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
```

Check the official documentation, you need lots more code, but in the end, you will have all you need.